# Composer не видит laravel/framework

Tags: laravel, composer

Хочу установить laravel/dusk. Зашел в корень проекта и

```
chernya@chernya:~/projects/project/app$ composer require --dev laravel/dusk
Using version ^4.0 for laravel/dusk
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - laravel/dusk 4.0.x-dev requires illuminate/support ~5.6 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - laravel/dusk v4.0.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.6 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22,v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - laravel/dusk v4.0.1 requires illuminate/support ~5.6 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22,v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - laravel/dusk v4.0.2 requires illuminate/support ~5.6 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22,v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - laravel/dusk v4.0.3 requires illuminate/support ~5.6 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22,v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - laravel/dusk v4.0.4 requires illuminate/support ~5.6 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22,v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - laravel/dusk v4.0.5 requires illuminate/support ~5.6 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22,v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.7.x-dev, v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - illuminate/support v5.6.10 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.11 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.12 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.13 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.14 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.15 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.16 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.17 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.19 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - illuminate/support v5.6.20 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.21 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.22 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.23 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.24 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.25 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.26 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.27 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.28 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.29 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - illuminate/support v5.6.30 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.31 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.32 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.33 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.34 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.35 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.36 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.37 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.38 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.39 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.8 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.6.9 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support 5.7.17 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support 5.7.18 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support 5.7.19 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.0 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.1 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.10 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.11 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.15 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.2 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.20 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.21 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.22 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.3 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.4 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.5 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.6 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.7 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.8 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support v5.7.9 conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev conflicts with laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.5.39, required as 5.5.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.39].
    - Installation request for laravel/dusk ^4.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/dusk[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


chernya@chernya:~/projects/project/app$ php artisan --version
    Laravel Framework 5.5.39
```

В папке vendor/laravel/framework всё на месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, у вас версия 5.5, для нее устанавливать нужно так:

```
composer require --dev laravel/dusk:"^2.0"
```

(с конкретным указанием версии)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/dusk#installation

Comment: да, так устанавливается, однако при выполнении команды php artisan, в списке доступных комманд нет dusk

Comment: быть может это как-то связано с тем, что проект на докере?

Comment: laradock@1c5913f9785:/var/www$ composer require --dev laravel/dusk:"^2.0"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.
Generating autoload files
> php artisan october:util set build
-
*** October sets build: 446
-
Ping? Pong!
-
Ping? Pong!

Comment: laradock@1c5913f6785:/var/www$ php artisan dusk


  Command "dusk" is not defined.

Comment: `Once Dusk is installed, you should register the Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider service provider` - вы добавили этот провайдер в свой config/app.php?

Comment: Спасобо! Всё заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Может в файле composer.json ты стер лару? сотри вендор весь и сделай `composer install`
потом уже пробуй ставить даск

Comment: в composer.json тоже всё на месте

Comment: переустановите вендор

Comment: не помогло, та же ошибка

Comment: кстати, не смущает? `locked at v5.5.39, required as 5.5.*`

Comment: что там у вас в `composer.json`?

Comment: возможно я так ставил, сайчас так "laravel/framework": "5.5.*", но это ничего не меняет

Comment: `composer require --dev laravel/dusk:"^2.0"`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/dusk#installation

Comment: А что мешает обновить до последней версии? там же пол часа отсилы. хотя бы до 5,6 и тогда 4 даск появится у вас) а так просто не дает из-за версии лары

Comment: буду пробовать.